# Якорный тег не работает в iPhone Safari

Tags: html, html5

Помогите решить проблему. Якорный тег не работает в iPhone Safari  код:

```
<a href="#vid" target="_self" class="w">Новости</a>
<a id="vid"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы пытаетесь проскролировать к строчному элементу – оба блока у вас на одной строке были, поэтому вы и не видели изменений.

```css
.w {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 0 200px;
}

#vid {
   background: #000;
   height: 200px;
   color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#vid" target="_self" class="w">Новости</a>
<div id="vid">Блок</div>
```